# Oracle returns rows- Crystal reports doesn't

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, oracle11g

I have a view i've created in Oracle. It returns rows, but when I use it through Crystal Reports, I get no rows. I've narrowed it down to this CTE in the query behind the view:

```
WITH PERIODS AS (
  SELECT
    ROWNUM-13 RN,
    TO_DATE('01-JUL-' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-6), 'YYYY')) AS FISCAL_YEAR_START,
    ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01-JUL-' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-6), 'YYYY')), ROWNUM-13) AS MONTH
  FROM
    DUAL
  CONNECT BY
    ROWNUM <= 24
)
```

This is quite weird, as if I replace this CTE with the following, it works (this second query is what the original report had, but due to logical issues in finding the financial year, it had to be changed).

```
WITH PERIODS AS (
  SELECT
    ROWNUM-13 RN,
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate,'yyyy'),6) AS FISCAL_YEAR_START,
    TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate,'yyyy'),6), ROWNUM-13),'MONTH') MONTH
  FROM
    DUAL
  CONNECT BY
    ROWNUM <= 24
)
```

Any idea why the second CTE causes Crystal reports to not pull any records? There are definitely rows being returned with both queries, just Crystal Reports doesn't like the first query (although I don't understand why as I would have thought Crystal would simply query Oracle for the data, and not be bothered by what is behind the view?!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I changed the CTE to the following and it worked:

```
 SELECT
    ROWNUM-13 RN,
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,6),'YYYY'),-6) AS FISCAL_YEAR_START,
    ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,6),'YYYY'),-6), ROWNUM-13) MONTH
  FROM
    DUAL
  CONNECT BY
    ROWNUM <= 24
```

I would still really like to know why the query behind the view was affecting Crystal Reports!

Answer (score 0):

In your first query this line:-

```
TO_DATE('01-JUL-' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-6), 'YYYY')) AS FISCAL_YEAR_START
```

would simplify down to:-

```
TO_DATE('01-JUL-2012')
```

Oracle will use the default date format to do the conversion.

Perhaps this is being set differently when you connect via Crystal Reports.  It is better practice to explicitly set the  date format by providing a second argument to TO_DATE.

Did Crystal Reports report an ORA error, like perhaps `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`?

Comment: It wouldn't simplify to that, as that would not dynamically pull the current financial year, which is what that statement achieve. No, there are no errors anywhere. The two statements return the same results when querying the table; it's just Crystal Reports thinks that it returns 0 rows with the first statement.

Comment: I understand that it would differ based on sysdate.  The point is that you have no second argument to `TO_DATE` which makes it depend on session-level settings which could vary depending on how you connect.

Comment: Ooo right, got ya! Then that does make perfect sense. What I don't understand though is why I can select data from the view still in one program, but not the other? I would have thought the date format behind the view is dependant on the oracle server, and not the applications settings (as it's a view, I would expect this part to be transparent to the application?)

Comment: Do a search for NLS_TERRITORY and NLS_DATE_FORMAT